# Sideways figure with rotated page number

Tags: floats, page-numbering, rotating

The submission requirements require that any landscaped image have the page number on the 11" side of the page, at the bottom and centered.  I can't figure out how to do this.

I'm using `sidewaysfigure` for my landscaped images.  They are on their own page.

Comment: Hi RockSalt, welcome to TeX.sx! You should add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your question, that's a much better way to get good answers quickly than putting "somewhat urgent" in the title.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=landscape) of the TeX FAQ

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you've interpreted the formatting requirements for landscape-oriented pages correctly, in that the page number is to be displayed centered on the long edge of the paper instead of along the short edge? I guess it's not impossible to have such a requirement, but it sure would be a highly unusual...

Answer (score 5):

Some extra packages are needed, although it is possible:

- [`floatpag`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatpag) for specifying page styles for "ordinary" floats; and
- [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) for easily defining page styles

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{rotating}% http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating
\usepackage{floatpag}% http://ctan.org/pkg/floatpag
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancypagestyle{floatpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear page header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \fancyfoot[C]{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{%
    \smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr\footskip+.5\textheight}{\rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \centering\thisfloatpagestyle{floatpage}%
  \rule{.8\textheight}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{A sideways figure.}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\section{Another section}\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

The newly created `floatpage` page style is created and used as `\thisfloatpagestyle` inside `sidewaysfigure` (provided by the [`rotating` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating)). The footer is subsequently made of a `r`ight-aligned box of zero height (`\smash`ed) with `\thepage` pushed up to the middle of the text block (`\footskip+.5\textheight`) and rotated by 90 degrees (`\rotatebox{90}`).

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was merely used to populate the document with dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style.

Comment: Why don't you introduce `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}` (for example) instead of `\rule{.8\textheight}{.5\textwidth}`?

Answer (score 4):

The new environment `Figure` uses always a landscape orientated page

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newenvironment{Figure}[1][!t]
  {\begin{landscape}\thispagestyle{empty}\begin{figure}}
  {\end{figure}\null\vfill\centerline{\raisebox{-2cm}{\thepage}}\end{landscape}}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{Figure}\centering
  \rule{.8\textheight}{.5\textwidth}
  \caption{A sideways figure.}
\end{Figure}

\section{Another section}\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```